# Nifi consumekafka doesn't accept upstream connection

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-nifi

I'm working with consumekafka poll messsage every interval 500 to 10000 records, while nifi iteration happen every 30 seconds once. i want to consumekafka once all jobs completed poll the next iteration. But consumekafka processor doesn't support upstream connection.

once puthdfs success i need to consume next iteration here i mentioned nifi workflow.

Workflow:

consumekafka -> mergecontent->convertRecord->updateattribute->puthdfs

Comment: @mattyb can you give me any suggestion on this question. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

after your consumekafka you can use the wait processor :

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.Wait/index.html

and release the signal after your puthdfs

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sure i tried that above approach but once successed put hdfs not working properly. isn't notify and wait independent processor?. Because once puthdfs notified i get puthdfs success file only and it is not working consumerecord successive response.